# Cookie not being registered, thus function not running

Tags: javascript, html

my code is below -

```js
var userName_cookie = document.cookie.split("; ").find(row => row.startsWith("username")).split("=")[1];

function noUserName() {
    console.log("noUserName()");
    document.getElementById("known").style.display = "none"; // make sure that the known div is hidden
    document.getElementById("not-known").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("submit-btn").onclick = function() {
        console.log("Submit btn clicked")
        userName_cookie = document.getElementById("enter-name").value;
        userNameKnown();
    }
}

function userNameKnown() {
    // add user name to cookie
    userName_cookie = document.getElementById("enter-name").value;
    document.getElementById("not-known").style.display = "none"; // make sure that the unknown div is hidden
    document.getElementById("known").style.display = "block";
    // edit known div to show username
    document.getElementById("hello").innerText = `Hello, ${userName_cookie}`
    // time (good morning, good evening etc.)
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    if(hours < 12) {
        document.getElementById("time").innerText = `Good Morning`;
    } else if(hours == 12) {
        document.getElementById("time").innerText = `Good Noon? or Afternoon, shall I say?`;
    }
    else if(hours > 12 && hours <= 16) {
        document.getElementById("time").innerText = `Good Afternoon`;
    } else if(hours > 16) {
        document.getElementById("time").innerText = `Good Evening`;
    }
    document.getElementById("known").style.display = "block";
}

if(userName_cookie === undefined) {
    noUserName();
} else {
    userNameKnown();
}
```

```css
#not-known {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
}
#not-known > input {
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#submit-btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#known {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Hello, What is your name -->
    <div id="not-known">
        <p>Hello, What is your name?</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name here" id="enter-name">
        <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit-btn">
    </div>
    <!-- If known -->
    <div id="known">
        <p id="hello">Hello,</p>
        <p id="time">Good</p>
    </div>
```

It is on my website home page, https://aaditya-baduni.github.io/. As you can see at the end of the JS code, `if(userName_cookie === undefined) {noUserName();}` it seems that the noUserName() function is not running, as I cannot the the 'known' div appearing.

I have to save the user's name as a cookie.
What I want to happen - The name to be registered as a cookie on click of submit input tag, the unknown div's display to be set as 'none' and the known div's display to be set as 'block' (the userNameKnown() function to be run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code that's reading the cookie will error before you get to the `if` statement:

```
document.cookie.split("; ").find(row => row.startsWith("username")).split("=")[1];
```

If the `.find()` doesn't retrieve any matches, it will return `undefined`, meaning you are calling `undefined.split()` which will cause an error.

The easy way to fix this is to use [conditional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
document.cookie.split("; ").find(row => row.startsWith("username"))?.split("=")[1];
```

The `?` before the `.split()` checks that it's not trying to call a function on `undefined` and will prevent the error and allow the code to continue on to run your if statement.